# Manage AngularJS modules version and releases using Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

Currently, I have multiple angular modules. A custom Grunt task concats, minifies and packages each module so it is ready to deploy. The only thing I haven't done yet is to manage the version of these modules.

Each project (one per module) contains a package.json file, in which I declare the name and version of a component :

```
{
    "name": "my-module",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    // etc.
}
```

So each module is built in a directory */dist/my-module/1.0.0/

But, in the module itself, I need to access its version. For example, in a controller, I declare a variable `$scope.version = '1.0.0'`. But currently, it is hardcoded in the controller script.

---

**First question**, is there a way the module could get the version from the package.json file ? Or that the grunt task building the application replaces a given flag in the scripts by the current version of the module ? (for example, I could declare my variable `$scope.version = 'FLAG_VERSION'` knowing that during the build grunt will replace the flag by the right value)

---

**Second question**, is there some grunt component which allows to tag the current version of a module in my VCS (SVN for example) and then increment the current version ? In short, perform a release of the module.

**Edit:** new question asked on that matter, see [Bump a specific version number on SVN using Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717541/bump-a-specific-version-number-on-svn-using-grunt)

---

Any help or lead will be appreciated !

Comment: https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump

Comment: https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant

Comment: Is grunt-bump working with another VCS than GIT ?

Comment: @Eria For that try https://github.com/arakir/grunt-bump-svn . For replacing the flag with current version in package.json , you can use https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace#multiple-matching

Comment: @PrayagVerma `'grunt-bump-svn' is not in the npm registry` :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**

I added a **grunt-ng-constant** task (thank you @Joe) to my grunt build to generate angular constants from the package.json file. It works great, I can now inject them into my directives and services. I had to add the module name to my package.json though, because the ng-constant task need it to identify the module for the generated constants. And the name declared in package.json was more a project name than the name of the module.

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "moduleName": "myModuleName"
    // etc.
}
```

Below the result of the ng-constant task :

```
angular.module('myModuleName')
.constant('appInfo', {name:'my-project',version:'1.0.0'})   
;
```

I changed my grunt build task to concat this generated script at the end of my application script, before minification. So now I can use appInfo in a service for example :

```
angular.module('myModuleName').service('myService', [ ..., 'appInfo', function( ..., appInfo ){
    // I can use appInfo.name and appInfo.version here !
}
```

> **Be careful!** I had a surprise applying this to several modules on the same page : if a constant with the same name is declared on two different modules, the value of the former will be overriden by the latter.
>   [AngularJS module.constant() : how to define a constant inside a module only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857670/angularjs-module-constant-how-to-define-a-constant-inside-a-module-only)

---

**Second question**

I asked another question, more precise, on that matter : [Bump a specific version number on SVN using Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717541/bump-a-specific-version-number-on-svn-using-grunt).