# AngularJS module.constant() : how to define a constant inside a module only?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a page, I have several Angular modules.
For each module I define a constant which contains the version of the module.

```
var module1 = angular.module('module1').constant('version', '1.2.3');
var module2 = angular.module('module2').constant('version', '2.0.0');
...
```

I though a constant was defined **inside** a module. But when I use the constant inside *module1*, the value I get is '2.0.0'...

Is there a way to define a constant (or anything else) which is proper to a module ?

**Edit**: for alternative solutions, could you please explain how to use it, for example in a controller declaration ?

```
module2.controller('myCtrl', function( $scope, $http, $q, ..., version ){
    // Here I can use the constant 'version'
}
```

Comment: see if you import `module2` as a dependency of `module1`, in that case the `version` constant may get overriden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modules and namespace / name collision in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406791/modules-and-namespace-name-collision-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very good question. I could think of a quick fix for this:

```
angular.module('module1').constant('module1.version', '1.2.3');
angular.module('module2').constant('module2.version', '2.0.0');
```

I don't know how much it suits your needs. But I hope it helps.

The main problem is the naming in Angular. You cannot have the same name for services/constants/values etc. They will be overwritten. I solved this problem with "namespaces" like I showed you above.

Example of injecting namespace like names: http://codepaste.net/5kzfx3

**Edit:**

For your example, you could use it like so:

```
module2.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', ... , 'module2.version'], function( $scope, $http, $q, ..., version ){
    // Here I can use the constant 'version'
}
```

Comment: How can I inject a constant having a dot in its name ? (for example in a controller inside my module)

Comment: angular.module().service(['module1.version'], function(version){}); You can have aliases. It's also a best practice to inject dependencies like this. Example: http://codepaste.net/5kzfx3

Comment: Doing what you suggest for the injection give me the following error : `Unknown provider: module1.infoProvider <- module1.info <- myCtrl`

Comment: this requires more explanation. why can't there be the same name for providers when they belong to different modules?

Comment: Because Angular wouldn't know what service to inject. If you have 2 modules with 2 services with the same name and you inject a service, Angular doens't konw which service to inject. Angular DI works on names. It searches the name of the dependency, not it's module of origin.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because module2 is overriding module1 constant.

You can use `moduleName.version` as a name, but it's not possible to use the same name.